# CodeIgniter URL mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to study codeigniter.
I am confused with URL `mod_rewrite`.
I use 2 pages: `home.php` and `about.php` in view directory, and call
them using controller `Site`.
In both the pages i gave links for it with controller functions home,
about respectively:

```
< a href='home'>Home</a>
< a href='about'>About</a>
```

when I type the URL as `localhost/Project/Site/home` and
`localhost/Project/Site/about`
it works efficiently.
My problem is when I call the URL
"localhost/Project" I can get the home.php but after that if I click on
any links (Home  / About ), the url will be  `localhost/Project/home` and can not access the page.

I am using `.htaccess` as the direction in the YouTube video

It may be a simple issue but i can't solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepending the path with a slash will make it link from your root url

I would just give it the path that works, something like:

`< a href='/Project/site/home'>Home</a> < a href='/Project/site/about'>About</a>`

right now it appends to the current url, as you see what is happening